# Calculate global median normalization in microarray

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics, median

I want to extract the Cy5 foreground/background for 4 arrays and subtract the background from the foreground values, and then log2 transform these values. Then, I want to calculate the global median normalization on these 4 arrays using the background subtracted Cy5 values. The median of each array will be used to scale. After normalization, all arrays should have a median of 1.

However, my code below evaluates median as 0 instead of 1. Why? And what should I change to get median of 1?

```
library(limma)
library(marray)


for(i in 1:4){
  name <- paste("sample", i, sep = ".")
  bg <- maRb(dat[,i])
  fg <- maRf(dat[,i])
  diff <- fg - bg
  diff[diff < 0] <- NA
  assign(name, log2(diff))
} 

data.prenorm <- cbind(sample.1, sample.2, sample.3, sample.4)
data.median  <- apply(data.prenorm, 2, median, na.rm = T)
data.norm    <- sweep(data.prenorm, 2, data.median)

colnames(data.norm) <- c("Array 1", "Array 2", "Array 3", "Array 4")

median(data.norm[ , 1], na.rm = T) 
median(data.norm[ , 2], na.rm = T)
median(data.norm[ , 3], na.rm = T)
median(data.norm[ , 4], na.rm = T)
```

data:

```
> dput(data.norm[1:4,1:4])
structure(c(0.335603031784438, 0.192645077942395, 0.280107919192734, 
4.59067615191555, 0, 0, -0.362570079384708, 6.14068778021722, 
-0.192645077942395, -0.263034405833793, -0.192645077942395, 3.4262647547021, 
-0.231325546106455, 0, -0.754887502163468, 6.13689620105484), .Dim = c(4L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Array 1", "Array 2", "Array 3", 
"Array 4")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in microarray processing, so I can only provide some acknowledged guess to what you are trying to achieve.

You see, the median of a median-normalized array is 0. To see this, imagine that you have a sorted data array of **x** and an array of equal length filled with median of **x**, call it **y**. The median of **x** is at its center position, and the median of  **(x-y)** will be at the center position as well, since subtracting a constant on each element of **x** does not vary their relative size. The center position of **(x-y)** is median(**x**)-median(**x**) by definition, and that is 0.

There are some good [discussion on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232261/how-can-i-prove-that-the-median-is-a-nonlinear-function) on this point here as well.

Now coming back to your point. I suspect what you meant to process are supposed to be in **log space**. That will give you median-of-median-normalized data 0. Then after converting normalized data back to **original space**, the median will be 1.

Here is a quick check using some dummy data:

```
dat = matrix(1:16, nrow = 4)
ldat = log2(dat)
ldat_norm = sweep(ldat,2,apply(ldat,2,median))
dat_norm = 2^ldat

median = apply(ldat,2,median)

> median
[1] 1.020621 1.002972 1.001136 1.000595
```